# Connect Git remote repository to unempty local folder

Tags: git, github

Every tutorial and book I've read on Git always address "new and clean" repositories and conditions. Mine does not fit this mold.

I have a folder holding Eclipse project files (Android app, specifically) called Research. I also have a GitHub repository, also called Research. It has files in its master branch...the very same as the ones I have in my local Research folder. It also has 2 additional branches, with more files in them.

1. How do I connect my local Research folder to the remote Research repository?
2. How do I retrieve files within the other branches of this remote repository into my local repository?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have the exact same files in your local repo as you do in your remote (GitHub) one, except the GH one has more branches - does that mean it wouldn't matter if you deleted the local files and just cloned your GH repository? Sorry, edit: Is the local Research folder just a plain folder/directory or are you already using git with it (making it a git repository)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do that. It's such a pain, though, to have to import the project back into Eclipse. It never goes well...there's always some dependency missing, issues with classpath, etc. The local folder USED to have git associated with it, but it has no git association now (it's a long story...a programmer with 10 years experience didn't want to listen to me...).

Comment: And about question 2: Do you just want to have copies of the *branches* in your local repository too, or do you want to just get the files out of the branches and into the master of your local repository?

Comment: Ok, following up your first reply: so you'd rather keep the local files and don't need the "master" branch of your GH repo (because the files are identical), but need the files from the other branches (either as branches or just the files, see my other question)?

Comment: Well, really what I'd like to do is merge the remote branch's files with remote master so that I can update my local repository. I do not know how to do any of this. The resources out there for Git pretend like I'm a solitary programmer. I'm working on a project with 3 other programmers (who do not know Git either...they are Material Engineering majors) and I'm at a loss for how to learn to do these things.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't merge remote branches with one another. Will post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've now tested this and it worked for me, but do make a backup copy of your local Research folder, just in case. (Or make a copy and try the steps with that copy first.)

Based on your comments I'm assuming your local files in Research are *exact* copies of the ones on the remote. You also said your local Research folder was not a git repository yet/anymore/again, but make sure it really isn't by checking there is no (hidden) .git folder in Research. If there is, remove it.

Now:

(Re)initialise Research with
`git init`

next, add your remote (the URL will look different if you use https;
'origin' is the name we pick to refer to the remote)
`git remote add origin git@github.com:youruser/yourrepo.git`

do a fetch of the remote
`git fetch origin`

Assuming the main branch of your remote is called 'master' (which is the default), do
`git reset --hard origin/master`
which will (re)set all tracking info of your local repo to that of your remote.

Now if you check which branches you have locally with
`git branch`
you should only see your master listed.

With
`git branch -r`
you will see all your remote branches.

Fetch them as needed (lbranchname is the name you give the new local branch;
it might make sense to use the same as the remote branch name rbranchname)
`git fetch git@github.com:youruser/yourrepo.git lbranchname:rbranchname`

If you check
`git branch`
now, it should list master and lbranchname, to which you can switch with
`git checkout lbranchname`

... Now work on branches or merge with master as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't really care about whether your repository is new or not when you add a remote.

You just use normal `git remote add` syntax.

Now, when you go to fetch from the remote, you may get some warning about 'no common commits' if the remote history is completely separate from yours.  How you would proceed depends on whether or not you have local history you want to preserve and a number of other factors.