# Re-connect local folder to remote repository

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, github-desktop

A number of months ago, I cloned a repository into a local directory. Since then, all git files were removed (not sure how), so I no longer have a connection to the remote repository and cannot pull any changes made in that remote repository since. I have also made many changes to my local code, so I need to be able to pull the remote code and merge it properly.

How can I re-connect my local directory to the same remote repository, and pull any new updates that have been made to the remote repository into my local directory since then?

If it helps, I can use Sourcetree or Github Desktop in addition to command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect Git remote repository to unempty local folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245275/connect-git-remote-repository-to-unempty-local-folder)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+connect+folder+remote+repository

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
git remote add
```

example

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

check the remote with

```
git remote -v
```

Also check the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)